# Can we make a call from twilio web browser to a mobile device which doesn,t have the same app or site similar to a cellular call?

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api, phone-call, twilio-click-to-call

I'm trying to place a one to one call from web browser to a mobile device with my number in it.
I'm using Twilio voice SDK to do it. It says congratulations on your first call but doesn't ring my device.
Is it possible to place a call using Twilio similar to a cellular call with both the parties talking to each other or just an automated message is played when you connect the call?

I want to connect my web app with Twilio voice SDK to call a number which I'll be dialing in it (eg: my own number)

CODE TRIED:
1)

```
client.calls
            .create({
                to: 'sip:kate@example.com',
                from: 'Jack',
                url: 'http://www.example.com/sipdial.xml',
            })
            .then(call => console.log(call.sid));
```

2. 

```
const device = new Device(token.toJwt());
        console.log(device)

            
        let call2 = await device.connect({ 
            params: {
              To: '+15551234567'
            } 
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do this to make test calls, have a look at the [Twilio Dev Phone](https://www.twilio.com/docs/labs/dev-phone).

You can run it from the Twilio CLI with the following command.

```bash
twilio plugins:install @twilio-labs/plugin-dev-phone
twilio dev-phone
```